How to get rid of mystery view on top of label in TextField compose
How do I hide view which is in light blue? .
I want to show border for a full TextField. I am trying to create a view like below. purple color will get updated to red or grey depending on state of textfield 
Here is my code
@Composable
fun TryText() {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val enabled = true
    val singleLine = true
    val colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()
    var state =  TextFieldValue("1234567890")
    val label = @Composable { Text("Phone Number", modifier = Modifier.offset(y = (10).dp).padding(all = 0.dp).background(Color.Transparent)) }

    BasicTextField(
        value = state,
        onValueChange = { state = it },
        modifier = Modifier,
        // internal implementation of the BasicTextField will dispatch focus events
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        enabled = enabled,
        singleLine = singleLine
    ) {
        TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
            value = "value",
            visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
            innerTextField = it,
            // same interaction source as the one passed to BasicTextField to read focus state
            // for text field styling
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            enabled = enabled,
            label = label,
            singleLine = singleLine,
            // update border thickness and shape
            border = {
                TextFieldDefaults.BorderBox(
                    enabled = enabled,
                    isError = false,
                    colors = colors,
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                    unfocusedBorderThickness = 1.dp,
                    focusedBorderThickness = 1.dp
                )
            }
        )
    }
}


I have tried few different combination do TextField, BasicTextField with TextDecoration but not able to achieve above.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

I have used TextField for this.


Here is the code.
fun ExampleEditText() {

    var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        label = { Text("Phone number") },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
            focusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .border(1.dp, Color.DarkGray, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .padding(4.dp)
    )
}


// Change Border-width, Color, CornerRadious, and Padding accordingly.



You need to add a top padding to the BasicTextField so the label has enough space:
modifier = Modifier
    .padding(top = 8.dp),

You can then remove the offset and padding modifiers from the label.
top = 8.dp is the same padding that is used by OutlinedTextField internally.
